# Better diffs with minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I'm looking at my test case results, and it's far to difficult to see where the one small failure in my test is coming from.

I'm dealing with reasonable sized data structures - and I don't want to change the `to_s` method so that it's slightly better for the **minitest** diff.

I've looked at the reporters but they don't seem to have anything like what I'm looking for. (I'm using ruby 1.9.3)

Is there any way that *minitest* or some library for minitest could highlight the part of the string that is different between two results?
Or is there something I'm missing that allows you to visually look at the diff more easily?

Edit: Example

```
Minitest::Assertion:         
--- expected
+++ actual
    @@ -1 +1 @@

    -#<struct MyModule::Swipe id=0, lat=37.62996, lng=-122.42115, route=#<struct MyModule::Route id=17, bus_name="test_name", stops=[#<struct MyModule::Stop id=29, name="Cool Stop">]>, date_time="2015-10-29T11:05:02+00:00">

    +#<struct MyModule::Swipe id=0, lat=37.62996, lng=-122.42115, route=#<struct MyModule::Route id=17, bus_name="test_name", stops=[#<struct MyModule::Stop id="29", name="Cool Stop">]>, date_time="2015-10-29T11:05:02+00:00">
```

Instead could show the line, and highlight in another colour the `id="29"` vs the `id=29` only. Minitest seems to show the diff based on the lines printed.

Comment: Can you post an example of an expected text and the real text? Or better: Show an example of a test with the result you want to get better.

Comment: @Knut thanks for the suggestion, done! :-) Also the command line doesn't have all the syntax colours that markdown shows either...

Comment: Can you post also your Struct-definitions? You don't want to adapt `to_s`, but Minitest uses the `inspect` command (often they have the same result, but you can redefine them separate). Is this a solution for you?

Comment: I'd really like an extensible solution, plug and play so to speak - to my eyes the solution would be to have a 'per string diffing' solution - instead it uses a 'per line' diffing solution, so if every change is on the same line it doesn't show it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

[pretty-diff](https://github.com/angelkar/pretty-diffs)

I had the same problem, and in case of invisible blank characters, this gem is still not good enough for debugging.  I end up adding `.inspect` to both String that I passed to `assert_equal` in minitest test case.